# Структура таблицы для вариативных товаров SQL

Tags: sql

имеется таблица товаров product с полями id, name, price и т.д., а так же имеется, относящееся к первой, вторая таблица с характеристиками этого товара product_variants с полями id, product_id, size, count.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, делаю запрос к БД на вывод всего каталога: `SELECT * from product p left join product_variants pv on p.id = pv.product_id WHERE stock = '1'` и выводится каждый товар с каждым размером, хотя нужно, чтобы вариативность товаров не выводилась, но по ней фильтровался каталог. Дайте пожалуйста наводку, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: "вариативность товаров не выводилась, но по ней фильтровался каталог" взаимоисключающие условия? или что значит "фильтровался"?

Comment: @Merlin извиняюсь за такую убогую формулировку. В общем есть страница каталога, в нём есть фильтр (по категориям, размеру, цвету и т.д.), получается сейчас, выводится каждый товар с каждым размером ТОВАР-1:РАЗМЕР 1; ТОВАР-1:РАЗМЕР 2 и т.д., а не так: ТОВАР-1(и в нём все размеры по которым происходит фильтрация, если таких размеров в нём нет, товар не появляется); ТОВАР-2(аналогично первому) и т.д. так вот, дайте пожалуйста наводку, как это реализовать. Дико извиняюсь, что так объясняю, надеюсь Вам понятно.

Comment: 1. Если вы хотите следовать условию "если таких размеров в нём нет, товар не появляется" то первой в запросе указывайте таблицу с размерами, а уже к ней можете left join основную таблицу или по другому: SELECT * from product p left join product_variants pv on p.id = pv.product_id WHERE stock = '1' and pv.SIZE is not null   2. Это реляционные записи, поэтому всё равно будут показываться все записи в виде ТОВАР-1:РАЗМЕР 1; ТОВАР-1:РАЗМЕР 2 и т.д., тут скорее вопрос в отображении, можно попробовать через partition by и rownum показывать значение поля ТОВАР только когда rownum=1, а иначе null

Comment: @Merlin Спасибо Вам огромное за ответ, очень помогли